# Subtract 1 from all digits of a hex which are smaller than given value d in C++

Tags: c++, hex, bit-manipulation

I have the following problem : I have a hex number (datatype : std::uint64_t) in C++, and the hex number contains all the digits from 1 to a given n. We also have given another digit d <= n. Is it possible to subtract 1 from all the digits of the hex number, which are greater or equal than n?
Here's an example of what I'm expecting :

```
hex = 0x42513, d = 3 -> Result : 0x42513
                               - 0x10101 <- the zero's are there because the digits
                              ----------    over them are smaller than 3
                                 0x32412
```

I have already tried out using a for-loop with left and right-shifts to achieve the result, but now I'm interested if there exists a solution without using a loop but instead **using bit manipulation only?**

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You need to write the code though. You need to decompose the number into 4 bit nibbles. Then you need to check each 4 bit nibble and substract 1 if the nibble is larger than 2. And then you need to recompose the new number out of the nibbles. All it needs ia a for loop, and bit shift (`<<` or `>>`) , bitwise and (`&`) and bitwise or (`|`)operators. If you don't want to use a for loop, you can unroll the loop.

Comment: The question meant to say "subtract 1 from all the hex digits of the number, which are greater or equal than `d`" correct, and not `n` ?

Comment: Looks like this may be easier by treating the numbers as a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some ways, even when `d` is not known in advance.

Using a [SWAR](https://www.chessprogramming.org/SIMD_and_SWAR_Techniques) average,

```
uint64_t L = 0x1111111111111111;
uint64_t v = L * d;
uint64_t decrementedHighNibbles = x - L + ((SWAR_AVG(~x, v, L) >> 3) & L);
```

Where:

```
uint64_t SWAR_AVG(uint64_t x, uint64_t y, uint64_t L) {
    return (x & y) + (((x ^ y) & ~L) >> 1);
}
```

For the rest of the explanation, let's consider just one nibble, standard SWAR techniques take care of applying the same operation to every nibble.

The basis for the trick is that the top bit of `avg(~x, v)` will be set if and only if `x < v`. That's the opposite condition of what we wanted, so instead of subtracting the top bit of the nibble from that nibble, 1 is subtracted unconditionally first, and then 1 is conditionally added back if the nibble was less than `d`.

As long as `d >= 1`, subtracting and adding 1 to the nibbles does not require the special SWAR-addition/subtraction, since there will automatically not be a borrow into the next nibble (which could only happen when subtracting 1 from a nibble that is zero). During the unconditional subtraction of 1 from every nibble, some borrows may cross between nibbles, but that would then be undone by the subsequent addition. If `d` can be zero then that would require more care.

Here is an alternative method using a "rounded up" SWAR average. Where `(x & y) + ((x ^ y) >> 1)` computes the average of `x` and `y` rounded down, `(x | y) - ((x ^ y) >> 1)` computes the average of `x` and `y` rounded up. The SWAR version of that is:

```
uint64_t SWAR_AVG_UP(uint64_t x, uint64_t y, uint64_t L) {
    return (x | y) - (((x ^ y) & ~L) >> 1);
}
```

While `avg(~x, y)` computes `x < y` in the top bit, `avg_up(~x, y)` computes `x <= y` in the top bit. We need `x >= v` so, so use `SWAR_AVG_UP(x, ~v, L)`:

```
uint64_t decrementedHighNibbles = x - ((SWAR_AVG_UP(x, ~v, L) >> 3) & L);
```

Comment: Why not `x - (L & ~(SWAR_AVG(~x, v, L) >> 3))` ?  Nice trick with the SWAR average, anyway.

Comment: Although I'm not sure that arithmetic operations (multiplication and addition) count as "using bit manipulation only", this definitely is what OP should have asked for -- branchless with low number of operations.

Comment: @BenVoigt that other formulation is fine too, might have slightly more latency due to having 3 operations that can only be done after taking the average, vs two (`x - L` can be scheduled before/during the average) but maybe that's splitting hairs

Comment: @harold One question about the SWAR_AVG function : `~L` eventually means `0x00000...`, and if we use an AND operation, the entire part `(x ^ y) & ~L` becomes 0, and then we shift it by one bit to the right, e.g `((x ^ y) & ~L) >> 1` which should be 0 as well. Is there any mistake in my thought process or could I really just leave this part out?

Comment: @asdasdqwer `~L` is not zero, it's 0xEEEE...

Comment: This is very nice! I've never seen SWAR stuff before. Here's my attempt at dealing with `n = 0` https://godbolt.org/z/ozdxnPxqE - I hope I got it right. If there's a `0` nibble in the input it carries over though.

Comment: @TedLyngmo BTW here's a "bit twiddling hack" (except this is hardly bit twiddling) to get L: `~T(0) / 15`

Comment: @harold Duh, facepalm :-) Updated version: https://godbolt.org/z/5aTr7oE4q

Comment: @harold just a small mistake, when using `SWAR_AVG_UP`, you should say `return x - ...` instead of `return x + ...`

Comment: @asdasdqwer that's right, I've updated it

Answer (score 3):

It's possible.  And fairly straightforward for constant `d`.

For the example with `d=3` and input `x`

Note that a nibble is >= 3 if

- The 8s bit is set
  *or*
- The 4s bit is set
  *or*
- The 2s bit and 1s bit are both set

Therefore

```
subtrahend = ((x >> 3) | (x >> 2) | ((x >> 1) & x)) & 0x11111111;
result = x - subtrahend;
```

Doing that for variable `d` in branchless code will not be fun. If branches are acceptable you could simply pre-analyze all the minimized logic functions and use `switch (d)` to pick from them.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version that is mostly useful when `d` is a constant:

```
if (d < 8) {
    return x - (((((x & 0x77777777) + (( 8-d) * 0x11111111)) | x) >> 3) & 0x11111111);
} else {
    return x - (((((x & 0x77777777) + ((16-d) * 0x11111111)) & x) >> 3) & 0x11111111);
}
```

For `d < 8`, we need to subtract one if either the high bit is already set (nibble is at least 8), or the lower three bits are high enough, which we can check with an addition. For `d >= 8`, we need to have the high bit set, plus a similar condition on the lower 3 bits.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any support for this specific operation in the standard library, but you could create your own function for it.

- Create an `index_sequence` with the number of nibbles in the type as template parameters.
- Extract each nibble by right shifting and do a binary `AND` `0xF`.
- Check if the result is `>=` the limit you've supplied
- Left shift the boolean result the same amount of bits.
- Combine the results with a fold over `|`.

```cpp
#include <climits>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <class T>
T sub(T val, std::type_identity_t<T> lim) {
    return val - [=]<std::size_t... I>(std::index_sequence<I...>) {
        return ((T((val >> (I * 4) & 0xF) >= lim) << (I * 4)) | ...);
    }(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT / 4>{});
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/dY4ehYW5W)

Comment: This is of course still looping and selecting each nibble separately, even if it's unrolled via TMP.  Other answers are constant-time.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, one could perhaps use the SWAR version in a fold expression to get a generic constant time solution. It looks pretty nice.

Comment: SWAR doesn't need a fold...

Comment: @BenVoigt Oh  ok, then I misread it and misimplemented it when I tried it out with generic unsigned types